Embedding a .so file while building Go project that uses C-API via C-Go interface
I have a Go project that uses the C-APIs of a C Library, via the C-Go interface. After the project is built, it requires a .so file while its execution. So now when I want to ship the project's binary I would also have to ship the .so file. Can I somehow attach the .so file with the binary so that it finds the .so file during runtime without providing the .so file together the executible.

how are you building the app , try using -static when building (not tried) ,  who owns the code for the .so ? ask them to compile as individual .o files and link them  in ...

You can’t embed the library, because the dynamic linker needs to link the objects on startup, before your code could extract an embedded library. You have to build statically
